# How to access another class data to access in viewDidlLoad in IPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios6

I am pass the some data from Nsobject class to UIViewController.In the view controller i access the data only inside the viewwillappear only.I cann't access the value in viewDidLoad. How can solve this

Comment: please post the related code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use delegate to access other class [example](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html) [examle1](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/03/19/simple-objective-c-protocol-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Call one function from ViewDidLoad for example

```
-(void)getData
{
 //you can access data here....
}
```

so create one function called getData and call it from viewDidLoad

Happy coding dear...!!!!!!!!